# Swfit4. Initial ViewController is the wrong for a split second, then it fixes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift4

In my app, the first time the app is used, the user is taken to a specific view controller (TutorialPageViewController). Every other time its used, the user is taken to a different view controller (HomeViewController).

To do this, I created a third view controller (FirstBlankViewController), where I show the logo of the app for one second. After that second, I call the appropriate view controller. This works, however when the app is opened, for a split second, you see the wrong view controller (ie TutorialPageViewController or HomeViewController) then the first one opens, and after a second it does the right thing.

But why is anything appearing before the FirstBlankViewController, which is set as the initial view controller. It shouldn't appear, even for a split second.

Here is the code in the FirstBlankViewController:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {

        let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")


        if launchedBefore  {

            print("Not first launch.")
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
            self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

        } else {
            print("First launch")
            self.dismiss(animated: false)
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialPageViewController") as! TutorialPageViewController

            self.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

    })

}
```

I hope its clear!

Thanks

Comment: hard to say. It could be just a screenshot of your app taken by the system.

Comment: There are two things that can be noted. 1) The `FirstBlankViewController` can be avoided by doing the decision making in the app delegate and setting the appropriate one as the `rootViewController` of your window (there are plenty of examples in the web) 2) As @Sulthan said, that could be a screenshot by the system in order to use it as a launch screen... which maybe is an indicator that you have not set a launch image/storyboard (?). If that is the case, you could maybe use that to show your logo...

Comment: @Alladinian. Regarding 2, I set up launchscreen.storyboard, and it didn't change this flickering. Regarding 1, I want to see the app logo for one second.

Answer (score 1):

The flicker is an iOS bug/feature that happens with **every app**, including system applications. It is a caching system that shows a screencap from the application. It tries to replicate the last state of the app, however, it's far from perfect. Note that the flicker occurs regardless you've set a launch screen/launch image or not.

Just ignore it and move on.